# Show Full Output button broken for all large outputs

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, output

I use *Mathematica* 9.0.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.3.

As an example of my issue, we can follow along with the example from the [documentation page for `$OutputSizeLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$OutputSizeLimit.html). Quoting from that page:

This produces output that is somewhat lengthy:

```
In[1]:= Expand[(x + 3 y)^27]
```

> **Out[1]=** x^27 + 81 x^26 y + 3159 x^25 y^2 + 78975 x^24 y^3 + 
>    1421550 x^23 y^4 + 19617390 x^22 y^5 + 215791290 x^21 y^6 + 
>    1942121610 x^20 y^7 + 14565912075 x^19 y^8 + 92250776475 x^18 y^9 + 
>    498154192965 x^17 y^10 + 2309623985565 x^16 y^11 + 
>    9238495942260 x^15 y^12 + 31979409030900 x^14 y^13 + 
>    95938227092700 x^13 y^14 + 249439390441020 x^12 y^15 + 
>    561238628492295 x^11 y^16 + 1089463220014455 x^10 y^17 + 
>    1815772033357425 x^9 y^18 + 2580307626350025 x^8 y^19 + 
>    3096369151620030 x^7 y^20 + 3096369151620030 x^6 y^21 + 
>    2533392942234570 x^5 y^22 + 1652212788413850 x^4 y^23 + 
>    826106394206925 x^3 y^24 + 297398301914493 x^2 y^25 + 
>    68630377364883 x y^26 + 7625597484987 y^27

Set `$OutputSizeLimit` to be rather small:

```
In[2]:= $OutputSizeLimit = 4000
```

> **Out[2]=** 4000

Now the same output as before is shown in a shortened form:

```
In[3]:= Expand[(x + 3 y)^27]
```

> **Out[3]=**
>
> A very large output was generated. Here is a sample of it.
>
> ```
> x^27 + 81 x^26 y + 3159 x^25 y^2 + 78975 x^24 y^3 +
>  1421550 x^23 y^4 + 19617390 x^22 y^5 + 215791290 x^21 y^6 + 
>  1942121610 x^20 y^7 + <<13>> + 3096369151620030 x^6 y^21 + 
>  2533392942234570 x^5 y^22 + 1652212788413850 x^4 y^23 + 
>  826106394206925 x^3 y^24 + 297398301914493 x^2 y^25 + 
>  68630377364883 x y^26 + 7625597484987 y^27
> ```
>
> [Show Less]   [Show More]   [Show Full Output]   [Set Size Limit…]

So far so good. But when I click any of the "Show Less", "Show More", or "Show Full Output" buttons, I am faced with the following error message:

> $OutputSizeLimit::noout: This output cannot be updated because Out[3] has no value.

This occurs for *any* "very large output" in any notebook. What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: What evaluation of `$HistoryLength` returns for you?

Comment: Wow: You got it in one guess! Absolutely right, I had set `$HistoryLength = 0` to help with memory consumption.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that you have empty history because you set `$HistoryLength = 0` (as you confirm in the comments). I recommend setting `$HistoryLength` to be at least `3` in order to get the `[Show Full Output]` button working in the most practical cases.